# Question regarding dx being infinitely small

Tags: calculus

In the book "Calculus Made Easy",there is a chapter on smallness of different degrees.There it was said that it was okay to treat high powers of a small fraction negligible and can be ignored.They took $dx$ to mean numeracally $\frac{1}{60}$ or $\frac{1}{1000}$ for example and discarded their high powers as relatively small to the other terms and ignored them.Now why do we need to take $dx$ infinitely small when we can take $dx=0.01$?In the end if we have something like $1000000060$ we discard the $60$.Then what is the need to take $dx$ infinitely small?Same goes for integration.If we can ignore the relatively small area,then we get the perfect area.What is the need to take $dx$ infinitely small?We can for example take $dx=1/64$ and can go with this forever.[image]
I have given a picture for examples.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a limit? Think about how the process of taking a limit is built into the definition of a derivative and integral.

Comment: I know that but I want an answer in context to relative smallness.

Comment: You cannot, for example, simply "ignore" the leftover area in the definition of the integral, unless you accept the fact that the limiting process makes that leftover area 'tend to' zero. The smallness of $dx$ determines the process of taking limits. By infinitesimally small we mean that we are working with limits.

Comment: Also, your example of discarding $60$ from $1000000060$ doesn't make sense, unless you specify the context. That number is unique, and discarding $60$ from it will give you a new number.

Comment: "In the end if we have something like 1000000060 we discard the 60"  Where on earth would that ever be an accept thing to do?  If you are willing to be "Meh... close enough" then you don't have to do *any* calculus for any reason.  you can just be slip shod and walk away when the bridges collapse.  I guess I don't understand your question.  If it's not obvious that it's unacceptable to just ignore errors and we need infinitisimals t actuall *know* what is going on then... I don't know what possible answer will be satisfying.

Answer (score 3):

It may be worthwhile to repeat here what @fleablood wrote in a comment (I hope I'm not mis-representing anything). Calculus is not about neglecting small quantities (relative small, or absolutely small, or any kind of small). Calculus is about computing precisely. Very precisely. It's about computing things that often involve some sort of infinite approximating process. This is often codified in the form of a limit. The language often employed is dynamical (e.g., $x$ vanishes, or tends to infinity). That is so for historical reasons and in order to appeal to a certain intuition that the formalism is trying to capture.

So, calculus is not the art of neglecting small quantities. It is the art very precisely quantifying how a quantity changes in relation to another quantity, with an emphasis on quantifying the effect of 'small' changes. The difference between small and large here is a question of perspective. It guides the questions we ask. For instance, asking if a given function has a local maximum is a question about the behaviour of the function in the very small scale. Asking if it has a global maximum is a large scale question. The tools of calculus are geared toward answering the former, not the latter (of course, we often answer the latter in a calculus setting, but the process of doing so is distinctly different than the classification of local extrema).

Now, this is from the perspective of pure mathematics. One may argue that from an engineering perspective one can (?) set a threshold of smallness and just discard things if they are small enough. Famously, for an engineer, $\sin(x)=x$ for all $x$ small enough. But it takes little effort to improve this and write the correct statement $\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ and then proceed to express $\sin(x)=x+r(x)$ where the remainder term satisfies $\lim _{x\to 0}r(x)=0$. This is the first order approximation of $\sin (x)$ expressed precisely and the remainder can further be analysed to produce more control over the approximation. In other words, we do not neglect $r(x)$. Rather, we replace it under control with something else, easier to compute, but we make sure not to lose track of our approximations. After all in the absence of further specification, $17$ is just a good an approximation of $\pi$ as any other value.

Comment: +1 in defense of calculus. Seriously one has to understand that calculus is not approximation and neither a fancy way of neglecting negligible things.